# I can't change position of textview and buttons in layout editor

Tags: android

My layout preview doesn't show the action bar only the textviews and buttons I added and when I add a new button or textview, it just goes to the top left corner of the screen even though I tried using Relative and Constraint Layouts. I've tried using `"Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"` but it doesn't solve it. I've had this issue since I installed android studio on my new PC.[Here's a screenshot of my layout preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0elqE.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Create Account" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show your layout xml code.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the xml code

Comment: check it https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_relative_layout.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally normal that your button is on the top left corner if you don't set its position.

If you add this to your Button:

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Than your Button will be in the center of the root layout.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Its just that on my old pc, I could just drag it to wherever i wanted it to be.

Comment: The problem with the drag&drop solution that you will set your UI elements with absolute position, but because of the lots of different screen size you need to work with relative positions so your UI will be the same on every device.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can even use ConstraintLayout for this problem. With the help of constraint layout handles you can easily set the button to the centre position.[constraint layout centering button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXgJC.png)

it can be done easily : join right handle first, then left handle, then top and bottom handle.

also with the help of this, layout will not be distorted on different screens